# sharepoint xslt customization documentation

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am looking to customize sharepoint xslt for xslt list view webpart/data form web part. Can someone point me to the resources/documentation to start with and also for advanced customization. I have fair knowledge in xslt. I am trying to render html from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Marc Anderson has written a series called "Unlocking the Mysteries of the SharePoint Data View Web Part XSL Tags". You'll find it on his blog http://sympmarc.com or on http://NothingButSharePoint.com. It is also available as an e-book that you can download directly from Marc's site.

Also, SharePoint Designer offers a friendly interface  with both code and design mode to tweak your xslt.

Comment: Nice references, Christophe.